# Polar decomposition of an operator and the partial isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A \in L(H)$, the space of bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H.$ I need to show that there is a partial isometry $U$ (i.e. $U^{*}U$ and $UU^{*}$ are projections), such that: $$A=U|A|$$ is the polar decomposition of $A,$ whereby $|A|=(A^{*}A)^{1/2}.$

Do you have any suggestion or a solution proposal ?

Many thanks for any comment.

Comment: I suggest reading [Wikipedia's Polar Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space).

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid using the Douglas' lemma.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{A^*A}$ denote the unique positive square root of $A^*A$. Then
\begin{align}
    \|Ax\|^2 &=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle \\ 
    & = \langle \sqrt{A^*A}x,\sqrt{A^*A}x\rangle \\ & =\|\sqrt{A^*A}x\|^2
\end{align}
Let $U$ be defined so that $U=0$ on $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{A^*A})$ and be defined on $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{A^*A})^{\perp}=\overline{\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{A^*A})}$ so that $U\sqrt{A^*A}=A$. Then $U$ is a partial isometry, and $A=U|A|$ is the desired decomposition, where $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$.

Comment: Many thanks. How does the operator $\sqrt{A^*A}$ act on $x\in H $ ? I am not quite sure if I understand the meaning of the positive square root of $\sqrt{A^*A}.$ Why one calls $UU^*, U^*U$ projections ?

Comment: @user249018 : A positive bounded operator such as $A^*A$ has a unique positive square root. That's a theorem you should have learned by now, or you would not be studying polar decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to work out the details, but basically you want to define an operator $U$ on (closure of) the range of $|A|$ by 
$$
U(|A|x)=Ax 
$$
and zero on $(AH)^\perp$. 
The only non-trivial part, I think, is to show that this is well defined. But this works, because  if $Ax=Ay$ then $A^*Ax=A^*Ay$ and now you can extend this equality to polynomials, take limits, and get $|A|x=|A|y$.

Next show that $U$ is an isometry on its domain, so it is a partial isometry, and in particular bounded.